# Keep the activity stack of a task when navigating from an activity

Tags: android

I have two tasks, with their respective stack of activities:

Task 1: A -> B -> C (foreground)

Task 2: D -> E -> F (background)

If from the recent list I go to Task 2, it returns to the foreground keeping its activity stack. If I do the same to return to Task 1, the behavior of the activity stack is the same, it's what I want!

Now, I want to do the above but from an activity. For example, call from activity C (in Task 1) Task 2 with its stack intact.

I tried calling D (FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) from C (in Task 1), but Task 2, as expected, returns to the foreground showing D, does not conserve the stack (Like when I access, from the recent list, to Task 2).

Can I get what I want (... call from activity C (in Task 1) Task 2 with its stack intact)?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show us some code? That always help with the interpretation of the questions. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your question is unclear. You can't "call a Task Stack" and you certainly can't do it from "A" if your stack is "A -> B -> C" since "C" would be the active top-most activity. Are you saying that you want to _switch_ tasks by launching "D"? So that instead of a new "D" you get "F" on the "D -> E -> F" stack?

Comment: It is correct "dominicoder", I apologize for the error. Activity D (in task 2) is not called from A, it is called from C (in Task 1) ... Correcting the question.